# Stack overflow error when hiding/unhiding rows based on calculated values in the Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, stack-overflow

I get a stack overflow error when trying to automatically hide/unhide rows based on calculated values in the Excel sheet.

The values are determined in functions in the form of:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(C32="Yes",D32=1,E32=1,F32=1),1,0),0)
```

If the value is 1, the rows are supposed to unhide, if the value is 0, they are supposed to hide.
I used a YouTube video to learn what code I need for this. There are 15 sections that I want to hide in the Excel sheet.

I get the stack overflow error with Excel sometimes crashing as soon as I try to do this for more than four sections. Apparently there are too many procedures stacking, because other Excel tabs also include macros that are running (basically the same, hiding/unhiding based on values; but in those cases values are chosen from a drop-down and not functions; so the code is different). However, the error always concerns the part described above.

Is there any way to debug, or split up the code, etc. to avoid the error?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim OECD As Range
Set OECD = Range("G32")

Select Case OECD
        Case Is = "1": Rows("33:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("33:38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim IndRights As Range
Set IndRights = Range("G43")

Select Case IndRights
        Case Is = "1": Rows("44:46").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("44:46").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim LandRights As Range
Set LandRights = Range("G47")

Select Case LandRights
        Case Is = "1": Rows("48:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("48:50").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Wages As Range
Set Wages = Range("G51")

Select Case Wages
        Case Is = "1": Rows("52:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("52:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Hrs As Range
Set Hrs = Range("G56")

Select Case Hrs
        Case Is = "1": Rows("57:58").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("57:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Accomm As Range
Set Accomm = Range("G60")

Select Case Accomm
        Case Is = "1": Rows("61:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("61:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Forest As Range
Set Forest = Range("G65")

Select Case Forest
        Case Is = "1": Rows("66:67").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("66:67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Water As Range
Set Water = Range("G68")

Select Case Water
        Case Is = "1": Rows("69:71").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("69:71").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Biodiv As Range
Set Biodiv = Range("G72")

Select Case Biodiv
        Case Is = "1": Rows("73:75").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("73:75").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Soil As Range
Set Soil = Range("G76")

Select Case Soil
        Case Is = "1": Rows("77:80").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("77:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Waste As Range
Set Waste = Range("G81")

Select Case Waste
        Case Is = "1": Rows("82:87").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("82:87").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Chem As Range
Set Chem = Range("G88")

Select Case Chem
        Case Is = "1": Rows("89:92").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("89:92").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim GhG As Range
Set GhG = Range("G93")

Select Case GhG
        Case Is = "1": Rows("94:95").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("94:95").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

Dim Energy As Range
Set Energy = Range("G96")

Select Case Energy
        Case Is = "1": Rows("97:98").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "0":  Rows("97:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hiding or showing the rows depends on the value of a cell. I think it makes sense to look at the cell value in Worksheet_Change and not in Worksheet_Calculate. Besides that, since you want to control some cells with VB, it is good to give them a name and do the control with a line, for example Rows("44:46").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("IndRights") .Value2 = "0") , "IndRights" will be the name of the cell (read about named ranges)

Comment: "Stack Overflow" in Excel usually comes from recursive calls to Event routines. You should try to set `Application.EnableEvents =False` at the top of event routines and `Application.EnableEvents =True` at the end to prevent that. And I never will understand why someone would want to use a `Select Case` for a simple If. Or, in this case, for a simple statement like `Rows("82:87").EntireRow.Hidden = (Waste = 0)`

Comment: Hi everyone, thx so much for the fast replies, very much appreciated. @FunThomas: you are officially my hero and saviour now! I really no nothing about VBA but you fixed it and simplified the code very much. Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Comment: Workbook_Calcluate event gets called every time rows/columns get Hidden or Unhidden.  This means that you're stuck in a loop of Workbook_Calculate events getting triggered every time you hide a row.  Try disabling Events to stop this from happening - just make sure that you have error handling which re-enables the events in the case of an error being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the entire procedure you've posted with something like this:

```
For Each rg In Array("33:38", "44:46", "48:50", "52:55", "57:58", "61:64", "66:67", _
                     "69:71", "73:75", "77:80", "82:87", "89:92", "94:95", "97:98")
    With Rows(rg)
        .EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("G" & .Row - 1).Value = 0)
    End With
Next
```